# debugging pl/sql function with custom types

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to use function tq84_select_star_from_table from answer to this question
[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803340/execute-immediate-in-plsql)

I created tq84_varchar2_tab,tq84_varchar2_tab_tab types and when I use function like in the answer to question, it works, but when I try to debug function I get this errors and debugging doesn't start.

```
ORA-06550: Row 13, column 16:

PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

ORA-06550: Row 13, column  3:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

When I change type of resultSet and return type of function to VARCHAR2, then debugging starts successfully.
I'm using oracle sql developer. I want to know what is wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, or at least an inability to handle custom types as bind variables. As a workaround you can change the generated code to skip the assignment to the bind variable:

Instead of:

```
:v_Return := v_Return;
```

set a dummy value:

```
:v_Return := null;
```

[image]

You can't just comment the old line out as that gets an 'invalid column index' error, which is something to do with it expecting the bind variable to be set - it doesn't like it you don't refer to `:v_Return` at all.

And of course you have to have recompiled the function for debugging. With that done, and the generated debugger code modified, it stops on breakpoints as expected.